# three.js, make dashed line through shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, line, shader

I'm trying to make a shader for my dashed line; but only I can get is white line from origin to .. +x direction(maybe)

If I render this curve (Ellipse.curve), they do just fine. And with shader don't..

..of course, I don't know why.. please help me;;

```
    <script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vs-orbit">
        uniform float time;
        attribute float sovereign;
        varying vec3 vColor;

        vec3 setColorBySovereign() {
            vec3 color;

            color.r = 0.5 - ( 0.5 * sovereign );
            color.g = 0.25 + ( 0.25 * sovereign );
            color.b = 0.5 + ( 0.25 * sovereign );

            return _color;
        };

        void main() {
            vColor = setColorBySovereign();
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
        };
    </script>
    <script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fs-orbit">
        attribute vec3 vColor;

        void main() {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, 1.0);
        };
    </script>

// ... Below is where use shader above;

Ellipse.prototype.createOrbit = function( soveregin ) {
    var shape, mater;
    var sov = soveregin || 0.0;

    shape = new THREE.Geometry();
        var v2;
        for(var i=0; i<721; i++) {
            v2 = this.curve.getPoint(i);
            shape.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(v2.x, v2.y, 0));
        };
        shape.computeLineDistances();

    mater = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        attribute: { soveregin: sov },
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vs-orbit'),
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fs-orbit')
    });

    this.orbit = new THREE.Line( shape, mater, THREE.LineStrip );
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem; after main(){} I shouldn't use ';' and other syntax errors too.

in fragment shader, I have to declare vColor with operator 'varying', just like vertex shader. In fragment shader; from GLSL Reference; varying is equal to in operator.